# I would love to know why is giving incomplete output (and why is not working)

Tags: javascript

Playing "You cant javascript under pressure" one of the exercises is this.

```
function longestString(i) {

    // i will be an array.
    // return the longest string in the array

    return i.reduce(function(last, current) {
        console.log(current);
        console.log(typeof current);
        return (typeof current == 'string' && current.length > last.length) ? current : last;
    });
}
```

The thing is, if you call the function like

```
longestString([true,false,'lol']);
```

Not only it doesn't work (and yes, I know how to do it with a for loop, I don't want to discuss about implementations, but why this particular one does not work), the weird part is the output:

```
longestString([true,false,'abc']);
> false
> boolean
> abc
> string
> true
```

Which is weird, because, if you have 3 elements in the Array, and 2 console.logs in the callback per element... You do the math.

Some input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

> If no `initialValue` was provided, then `previousValue` will be equal to the first value in the array and `currentValue` will be equal to the second.

It's not a bug in JavaScript.

Your callback function is called twice.

First call:

`last` = `true`
`current` = `false`
`typeof current` = `boolean`
`typeof current == 'string' && current.length > last.length` = `false`
so the callback returns `true`

Second call:

`last` = `true`
`current` = `'abc'`
`typeof current` = `string`
`typeof current == 'string' && current.length > last.length` = `false`
so the callback returns `true`

I suggest changing your implementation to:

```
return i.reduce(function (last, current) {
    console.log(current);
    console.log(typeof current);
    return (typeof current == 'string' && current.length > last.length) ? current : last;
}, ''); //  <-- empty string
```